# TFS 2012 "Assigned To" in WI and "Assign To" on the little dropdown on the web show different people

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

All the correct users show up when I use the drop down in the Work Item "Assigned To" field. When I go to re-assign them on web using the little down arrow and select "Assign To" next to the listed work item in the query list it has missing people and groups. For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference between TeamExplorer drop down and WebAccess. Are you sure you are on the same TeamProject and WorkItem type? Or do you mean in some list view? Maybe it only shows the members of the "TeamProject Team" group, which might differ to possible users of the Assigned To field.

Comment: Looking on the web access I can pull up a work item. In the work item it has "Assigned To:", which is a drop down. It lists all my groups and users as desired. If I pull this same work item up in a query, the query list will provide me a way to edit the work item selected by clicking the little down arrow on the left side. One of the options is "Assign To:". When clicking that it shows a list of people which has some but not all from the drop down inside the work item. this is my problem.

Comment: I checked that on our TFS and it shows only the first 20 users in the list (alphabetically ordered), otherwise it would have listed about 100+ which is too much for such a menu.

Comment: I was able to get around it by using the edit feature in the same drop down. I was trying to mass edit 200 work items. I see what you're saying though. They could have made it scrollable :)